# Looking for a regulation to handle 4.2 to 5.5 V in and fixed 4 V out

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I set up a device with the LM1117, but I think it is barely a LDO (NPN) and suffering to do what I want. I'm looking at the LT1083/LT1084/LT1085 now, and in reading the data sheet, I think it has a 0.9 V drop out.

What is the best way to handle an input of 4.2 to 5.5 V and maintain 4.0 V out?  Will I see a low drop out part in this percent?

Here is my PSU currently:
[image]

Max. load is maybe 250 mA, but RMS is closer to 80 mA. The device it supports is a game controller, but the actuators may draw up to 250 mA initially. The power source will provide 1 A.

Comment: Please list voltage or current behind numbers IE: (-5.5V). What are current requirements?

Comment: Ahh good point. Max load maybe 250mA but rms is closer to 80mA. The device is supports is a game controller but the actuators may draw up to 250mA initially.  Also ( 4.2 - 5.5) was meant to show a range. Will edit and fix that.  Source of power Will provide 1 amp.

Comment: Thanks, please edit the question.

Comment: Is the 4.2V input being supplied from a battery?

Comment: Could you just replace your switching converter with a buck-boost design and not worry about the VCC voltage changing? It will cost a few cents more but it could improve efficiency a lot (especially for the 5.5 V input case).

Comment: yes that is being considered, of course more effort involved there so hoping for another solution.

Comment: As it seems, and very surprising to me, USB is never 5v, and varies a lot. the power source in the case is USB.  The original design was assume 5v and works great if that is the input but some USB systems drop very low.  4.2 was the lowest I have seen. I can not go lower and will not support USB level that low. but want to do what I can.

Comment: Going to give this a try, and if that fails, redesign. 

https://www.ti.com/product/TPS7A24

Answer (score 0):

As The Photon [pointed out in a comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699631/looking-for-a-regulation-to-handle-4-2-5-5-in-and-fix-output#comment1863112_699631), the solution would be to get rid of the separate linear regulator as prior stage to the switcher, altogether.

You'd want a buck-boost regulator switcher IC instead of your two regulator ICs, which directly converts 4.something to 5.something V to 5.0V.

These are relatively abundant, but [TPS631000](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS631000) might be a hobbyist- and small production run-friendly choice (I mean, 0.5mm pitch, yes, but definitely possible to reflow at home with hand-squirted solder paste and hand-place part.)